# Transparent PNG Image in HTML

Tags: html, image, png, transparent

I would like to have [this picture's](http://bit.ly/ijG0ca) background transparent to the webpage I am creating. I am using Paint Shop Pro 9 and am having trouble making the background transparent. I tried the PNG optimizer but still shows a white background.

Thanks

Comment: So when you open the image in PaintShop Pro 9 and save it out, the background turns white?

Comment: what browser?  IE doesn't allow transparent png's without a special css filter.

Comment: Is the picture showing white ONLY in a browser?  Or is it showing white even in windows?

Comment: it's showing the picture in a white background.

Comment: That's because you haven't made the picture transparent yet.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't about this kind of stuff. Read the FAQ.

Comment: @Daniel - you really need to be much more explicit when you are explaining your problems.  You say "it's showing the picture in a white background." But WHERE is it showing like that?  In your browser?  Or in an image viewer?  Or Paint Shop Pro?  If you want useful answers you need to be explicit and give as much detail as possible.  Otherwise it's impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It shows up correctly (with transparency) in my browser. If you're having problems with IE6, try this:

```
<div style=”position:relative; height: 188px; width: 188px;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader 
(src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/7/2/d/9/11954460371278569538three_palm_trees_gregoir_03.svg.hi.png',sizingMethod='scale');”></div>
```